# How to make a sum of columns in assembly 64bit?

Tags: linux, assembly, 64-bit, x86-64, nasm

I don't know how to calculate the sum of columns. I tried to calculate the sum of columns but I can not add a certain number of bytes which I need. For example: I have matrix of `dd` (4 bytes), and I need to add first number (2) in matrix and under him (1). Between them is 12 bytes and I can't add in cycle like this `[matrix+r9*12]`. Help please!

```
global _start

section .text

_start:

    xor r8, r8          
    mov rcx, 2          
    for:
        mov r9, rcx
        dec r9
        add r8d, [matrix+r9*4]      

    loop for
    mov eax, r8d
    add eax, 30h
    mov [out], eax
    mov rax, 4
    mov rbx, 1
    mov rcx, msgAnswer
    mov rdx, msgAnswerLen
    int 80h

    mov rax, 4
    mov rbx, 1
    mov rcx, out
    mov rdx, 28             
    int 80h

    mov rax, 1
    mov rbx, 0
    int 80h

section .data

    matrix: dd 2, 3, 3          
        dd 1, 3, 3      
        dd 3, 4, 4          
    msgAnswer: db 'sum of columns: '
    msgAnswerLen equ $ - msgAnswer  

section .bss

    out: resd 9
```

Comment: [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](//stackoverflow.com/q/46087730).  Also, why are you printing 28 bytes when only the first byte of `out` holds a valid ASCII character?  If you want to write result to stdout in binary, don't add `30h` to it.  But if you want to convert from binary to a decimal string, adding `30h` only works for 1-digit numbers.  See [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library?](//stackoverflow.com/a/46301894)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of the offset within the matrix in a different register from the loop count.  One way to do that is to store that in `R9`.

```
    xor r9,r9
for:
    add r8d,[matrix+r9]
    add r9,12
    dec rcx
    jnz for
    lea rax,[r8d+30h]
```

Not that I've also replaced the `loop` instruction with two equivalent instructions that sequence better, and the two instructions that follow it with an equivalent single instruction.  The `mov [out],eax` will be the same even though the calculation uses the larger register.

Comment: There is rarely if ever a reason to use 32-bit addressing modes in in 64-bit mode. `lea rax, [ebx+30h]` has two unnecessary prefixes: REX.W and address size, while `lea eax, [rbx+30h]` does exactly the same thing with no prefixes. (Changing `lea rax, [r8d+30h]` to `lea eax, [r8+30h] only avoids one prefix, because it still needs REX.B, but it's still an improvement.)